# How is this "add" method used on a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python and can't seem to find any reference for an add() method for dictionary data structure in python. But I was debugging a python code and found the following code.

```
token = {}
try:
    token[t].add(offset)
except KeyError:
    token[t] = set([offset])
```

Below are the set of imports used in the code.

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
import copy
import json
import math
from optparse import OptionParser
import os
import signal
import string
import sys
```

From where does that add() method comes for the dictionary?

Comment: `token[t]` is not necessarily a dictionary. Have a look at `type( token[t])`.

Comment: It's not about `dict`, there can be anything in `token[t]`

Comment: The `add` is not performed on the dictionary but on a item in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add` method that you see is not for the dictionary, but rather for an item *in* the dictionary (a `set`)

`token[t]` accesses the item mapped by `t`

and

`token[t].add` calls `add` on the item mapped by `t`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. It's on the `set` stored as a value, not on the `dict` itself.